# Django seems to strip https from static file URLs – why?

Tags: django, https, static-files

Having just switched my site to be served over SSL, I'm having trouble getting Django to pick up on the correct generated URL:s for static files.

My `STATIC_URL` setting is in the form of `https://example.com/assets/static/`

When I do `{% static 'css/file.css' %}` in a template, the path comes out as `http://example.com/assets/static/css/file.css` — which is the same as before.

Things I've tried to remedy this:

- Making sure that I'm on the latest commit, with the correct settings.
- Ran `python manage.py collectstatic`
- Restarted nginx/gunicorn/memcached
- Deleted `*.pyc`-files, just in case

The same thing happens with `MEDIA_URL`. However, if I drop into an interactive shell and import a model, and then print out the `.url` property of an uploaded image file (for example), it comes out with the correct `https://`-prefix.

Running Django 1.9.5, using `CachedStaticFileLoader` for static files, Gunicorn (v 19.4), and template caching. Cache engine is memcached.

Any ideas on what's going on?

**Edit**: Settings changes for `STATIC_URL` and `MEDIA_URL` are not being picked up at all, it seems, although other code changes seem to work. I have not idea what's going on...

Comment: Do you have `os.environ['HTTPS'] = "on"` and have you tried using relative `STATIC_URL` ? Also it is a good thing to have redirect from http to https either in guncorn, either in nginx, that should serve the static

Comment: I use the `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` setting to communicate the HTTPS status to Django from Nginx, and it seems to be working (I can output the result of `request.is_secure` in a template, and it returns `True`). I tried adding `HTTPS=on` to the env, but it had no effect on my issue.

I suspect something else is going on, as the value in `MEDIA_URL` and `STATIC_URL` does not seem to be picked up at all, relative or not. :-(

Answer (score 2):

The answer was that no settings changes were picked up at all – the Gunicorn process was hung up trying to restart somehow (no matter how many times I told it to), keeping the old process going. Changes to templates etc got picked up (as those are not python files), but the `STATIC_URL` was never updated.

Stupidly simple answer: reboot ALL THE THINGS.